# Morris.js issue in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, raphael, morris.js

I am following Railscast #223 to try to get some simple line graphs into my Rails 3.2.9 site using Morris.js and Raphael.  I've downloaded the raphael and morris javascript files and added them to the vendor/assets/javascripts folder, then added the relevant lines to the application.js:

```
//= require raphael
//= require morris
```

I then created a simple HTML div for the chart:

```
<div id="annual"></div>
```

And added the relevant CoffeeScript to the associated javascript file (tenants.js.coffee):

```
jQuery ->
    Morris.Line
        element: 'annual'
        data: [
            {y: '2012', a: 100}
            {y: '2011', a: 75}
            {y: '2010', a: 50}
            {y: '2009', a: 75}
            {y: '2008', a: 50}
            {y: '2007', a: 75}
            {y: '2006', a: 100}
        ]
        xkey: 'y'
        ykeys: ['a']
        labels: ['Series A']
```

The page loads fine but without producing the graph.  I'm new to CoffeeScript so I'm not sure how to debug this.  I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing.

Thanks!

Comment: Any errors in the JavaScript console? Are you including jQuery as well?

Comment: No errors.  I am using jQuery as prepackaged in Rails.

Comment: Are you sure the `<div id="annual">` is on the page and your `tenants.js.coffee` is being loaded? Are you sure the indentation in your CoffeeScript is right? Most people use spaces for indentation in CoffeeScript since it is so sensitive to whitespace.

Comment: I'm sure the div is on the page.  I've tried spaces versus tabs but still no luck.  How do I check if the coffeescript file is being loaded?  Tenants.js is, according to my server log.

Comment: You could always throw a simple `console.log` call into `tenants.js.coffee` (say one inside the `jQuery ->` and one outside) to see what's being loaded and run. That will at least give you a quick and easy way to see what's running.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution in CoffeeScript:

```
Morris.Line({
  element: 'annual'
  data: [
    {y: '2012', a: 100}
    {y: '2011', a: 75}
    {y: '2010', a: 50}
    {y: '2009', a: 75}
    {y: '2008', a: 50}
    {y: '2007', a: 75}
    {y: '2006', a: 100}
  ]
  xkey: 'y'
  ykeys: ['a']
  labels: ['Series A']
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If were are using simple js file, example annual.js, there are use code:

```
jQuery(function() {
  return Morris.Line({
    element: 'annual',
    data: [
      {y: '2012', a: 100},
      {y: '2011', a: 80},
      {y: '2010', a: 75},
      {y: '2009', a: 70},
      {y: '2008', a: 65},
      {y: '2007', a: 60},
      {y: '2006', a: 55}
      ],
    xkey: 'y',
    ykeys: ['a'],
    labels: ['Series A']
  });
});
```

For converting js to coffee = http://js2coffee.org/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your CoffeeScript is indented (spacing) properly.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing just delete
//= require turbolinks
.This solved by issue